# Next.js after build and deploy the .next to the cpanel, the code work but it try to access __next/static/chunks/.js and .css from the old build

Tags: reactjs, next.js

It's the first time i am using next.js, i am working on modify some functionality in local it's works fine, but after build npm run build, then deploy to the server, the code works, but i have problem with some files in __next/static/chunks/.js and .css , the try to access files from the old build, and i get 400 error Bad request, is it related to cache on the server, there is no cache on the browser, any help appreceated

I try to reset the server, or wait one day to check if related to cache,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `output: "standalone"` and copy `.next/static` to `.next/standalone/.next`

Following my build script:

```
"build": "next build && cp -r .next/static .next/standalone/.next && cp -r ./public .next/standalone"
```